# Vitest error No <functionName> export is defined on the <path>

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, vitest

Here i have a function which formats Weatherdata fetched from an api, i want to mock this api call to have consistent weather data to only test the pure formatting function
**weatherApiController.ts**

```
import { getWeatherData, formatWeatherData} from '../controller/weatherApiController'
import { describe, expect, vi, test } from 'vitest'



export async function formatWeatherData(start: String, end: String){
    let data = await getWeatherData(start, end)
    let formattedTemps = []
    for(let i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++){
        formattedTemps.push({datetime: data.days[i]['datetime'], tempmax: data.days[i]['tempmax'], tempmin: data.days[i]['tempmin']})
    }
    console.log(formattedTemps);
    
    return formattedTemps
}


export async function getWeatherData(start: String, end: String) {
    try{
        let response = await fetch(`https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/Wermelskirchen/${start}/${end}?unitGroup=metric&include=days%2Ccurrent&key=<apiKey>&contentType=json`);
        if(!response.ok){
            throw new Error(`HTTP Error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        let data = await response.json()
        console.log(data);
        
        return data
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error)
        return null
    }
}
```

***weatherApiController.test.ts***

```
test('mock3', async()=> {
    let expected = [
  { datetime: '2023-03-12', tempmax: 10.4, tempmin: -0.2 },
  { datetime: '2023-03-13', tempmax: 15.4, tempmin: 9.1 }
]
    vi.mock('../controller/weatherApiController.ts', async() => {
        const actual = await vi.importActual("../controller/weatherApiController.ts")
        return {
          actual,
          getWeatherData: async() => {
            number: 3
          },
          formatWeatherData: async() => {
            number:4
          }
        }
      });
      const result = await formatWeatherData('2023-03-12', '2023-03-13')
      expect(result).toEqual(expected)
})
```

***This is t*he error i get**
Error: [vitest] No "formatWeatherData" export is defined on the "../controller/weatherApiController.ts" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?
If you need to partially mock a module, you can use "vi.importActual" inside:

i appreciate any help!

I tried to mock the API call to get consistent weather data. I expected to have a constant return value of the function.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue after implementing the suggested syntax from Vitest.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where my mock looked like this:

```
vi.mock('@/api/Client', () => {
    const API = VueMocks.API
    return API
})
```

and vitest was erroring with

> ```
> Error: [vitest] No "default" export is defined on the "@/api/Client" mock. 
> Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?
> If you need to partially mock a module, you can use "vi.importActual" inside:
>
> vi.mock("@/api/Client", async () => {
>   const actual = await vi.importActual("@/api/Client")
>   return {
>     ...actual,
>     // your mocked methods
>   },
> })
> ```

Reading up the vitest docs, There was a [warning in the vitest document under `vi.Mock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock) that said:

> WARNING
>
> If you are mocking a module with default export, you will need to
> provide a default key within the returned factory function object.
> This is an ES modules-specific caveat, therefore jest documentation
> may differ as jest uses CommonJS modules. For example, ts
>
> ```
> vi.mock('./path/to/module.js', () => {   return {
>     default: { myDefaultKey: vi.fn() },
>     namedExport: vi.fn(),
>     // etc...   } })
> ```

In my actual `@/api/Client` file, which was a ts file, it looked like this

```
export export class API { ... }

<Stuff>

export default new API(shallowReactive)
```

So in my case I had to have a `default` that was returned, in addition to the module I wanted returned.

I had to do something like this

```
vi.mock('@/api/Client', () => {
    const API = VueMocks.API
    return {
        default: { ...API },
    }
})
```

Where for me `VueMocks.API` was a var object I had made myself that specified all the mocks required by the API already.

In your case, you would probably have to do something like

```
vi.mock('../controller/weatherApiController.ts', async() => {
    const actual = await vi.importActual("../controller/weatherApiController.ts")
    return {
      ...actual,
      getWeatherData: async() => {
        number: 3
      },
      formatWeatherData: async() => {
        number:4
      }
    }
```

Since the exports in your file above are `export async function formatWeatherData([...])` and `export async function getWeatherData([...])`

**It also looked like you forgot to add the `...` for copying the value of actual, because in yours it is `return { actual` when it should be `return { ...actual`**

Comment: I was missing the `default` key in the returned mock object. The test case worked fine after I added it.